# How do you retrieve all places where an injectable is provided?

Tags: angular, webstorm

Is there any tools or way for angular2 to retrieve where an injectable is provided in a large project? Like a find usage but instead a find providers of "injectable" that will list all components or modules that are providing the injectable in question?

Thank you!

Comment: In Visual studio code, go to your injectable and rename it with `F2`. It will open all files containing the injectable. You can also right click and chose "Find all occurences".

Comment: @trichetriche From my perspective, F2 is a equivalent of "find", in a large project, this may return 100-200 occurrences because it will also show the using while in fact it have been provided a few places.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought QWERtY and AZERTY had the same shortcuts when it comes to function keys. Then use the "rename" key ! And if there's too much occurences, then use the "find all occurences" of the visual studio context menu, which shows an UI for finding where it's used.